# searching on name instead of id on sql

Tags: laravel

I have search input in my products page. I can search on name on description and on category if I type the id but that's not really practical how i change this sql so i can search on the name of the category instead of the id.

DB i have Products | name,description,category_id
Categories | id,name

```
    public function scopeFilter($query,array $filters){
    if ($filters['search'] ?? false){
        $query
            ->where('name', 'like', '%' . request('search') . '%')
            ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%' . request('search') . '%')
            ->orWhere('category_id', 'like', '%' . request('search'). '%');
    }
}
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the current code? Theres a `where`  condition for the name applied

Comment: this only works if i say search for me id 1 of categories not if i say search for me the category pants for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the category is a related model search on the relationship:

```
public function scopeFilter($query,array $filters){
    if ($filters['search'] ?? false){
        $query
            ->where('name', 'like', '%' . request('search') . '%')
            ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%' . request('search') . '%')
            ->orWhereHas('category', function ($q) {
               $q->where('name','like', '%' . request('search'). '%'
            });
    }
}
```

This is assuming you have defined your relationship in your model.

Answer (score 0):

Since the category is a related model search on the relationship AND I suggest using this code: ‌

```
public function scopeFilter($query,array $filters) {
    if ($filters['search'] ?? false){
        return $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . request('search') . '%')
            ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%' . request('search') . '%')
            ->orWhereHas('category', function ($q) {
                $q->where('name','like', '%' . request('search'). '%');
        });
    }

    return $query;
}
```